# Numpy sorting by increasing datetime

Tags: python, datetime, sorting, numpy

I have an first array `i` containing datetime elements (with the shape (33416,)) and a second array `m` containing floats values (with the shape (33416,20)). This correspong to 20 measurements made at a specific instant.
I would like to sort `i` array according to increasing datetime values in `i` and sort lines of `m` array accordingly in order to have increasing instant of measurements and its corresponding 20 measurements at this instant.
Can some help me ? or understand my needs ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use numpy for this. Assuming you have:

```
dates = numpy.array([datetime(2012,02,03,12,00,00), datetime(2012,02,03,15,00,00), datetime(2012,02,03,13,00,00)])
values = numpy.array([[1, 1], [3, 3], [2, 2]])
```

You can do at first:

```
unified = numpy.concatenate((dates.reshape(len(dates), 1), values), axis=1)
```

This will merge your two list, which considering what you want should be a better suited way to hold your data anyway. So now you have:

```
unified = array([[2012-02-03 12:00:00, 1, 1],
                 [2012-02-03 15:00:00, 3, 3],
                 [2012-02-03 13:00:00, 2, 2]], dtype=object)
```

Now you can do:

```
unified = numpy.sort(unified, axis=0)
```

This will sort after date. Now if you still want just the separate lists you can get them with:

```
unified[:, 0]

>>> array([2012-02-03 12:00:00, 2012-02-03 13:00:00, 2012-02-03 15:00:00], dtype=object)

unified[:, 1:]

>>> array([[1, 1],
           [2, 2],
           [3, 3]], dtype=object)
```

**EDIT** after your comment
Ok now that I fully understand what you want you can achieve that by replacing

```
   unified = numpy.sort(unified, axis=0)
```

with:

```
   unified = numpy.array(sorted(unified, key= lambda x: x[0]))
```

**EDIT**

have you tried what I just suggested? In my terminal:

```
    unified = numpy.array([[datetime(2012,02,03,12,00,00), 4, 1],[datetime(2012,02,03,15,00,00), 5, 2],[datetime(2012,02,03,13,00,00), 2, 1]], dtype=object)
    >>> unified
        array([[2012-02-03 12:00:00, 4, 1],
               [2012-02-03 15:00:00, 5, 2],
               [2012-02-03 13:00:00, 2, 1]], dtype=object)

    >>> unified = numpy.array(sorted(unified, key=lambda x: x[0]))
    >>> unified
        array([[2012-02-03 12:00:00, 4, 1],
               [2012-02-03 13:00:00, 2, 1],
               [2012-02-03 15:00:00, 5, 2]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is almost that. But this is also sorting all the columns by increasing order. I only want according to time unless I messed up my measurements .... I'll take a look on numpy.sort documentation...

Comment: Not so obvious problem... This representation is nice : `unified = array([[2012-02-03 12:00:00, 1, 1],[2012-02-03 15:00:00, 3, 3],[2012-02-03 13:00:00, 2, 2]], dtype=object)`
But my case is for example from `unified = array([[2012-02-03 12:00:00, 4, 1],[2012-02-03 15:00:00, 5, 2],[2012-02-03 13:00:00, 2, 1]], dtype=object)` I want to obtain `array([[2012-02-03 12:00:00, 4, 1],[2012-02-03 13:00:00, 2, 1],[2012-02-03 15:00:00, 5, 2]], dtype=object)`

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED TO OBTAIN !!!
THANK YOU. 
(This should be implemented in an option of numpy.sort function.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking - your question is vague - what does "sort lines of `m` array accordingly in order to have increasing instant of measurements and its corresponding 20 measurements at this instant" mean?

But, here's the answer to what I think you are asking:

```
def special_sort(i, m):
    myList = zip(i, m)
    mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    return myList
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok I should simplify my request. For example, `i` contains 3 instants of measurements :
[datetime(2012,02,03,12,00,00),
datetime(2012,02,03,15,00,00),
datetime(2012,02,03,13,00,00)]
And `m` contains 2 measurements at each instant
[[1., 1.],
[3., 3.],
[2., 2.]]
I want to obtain `i` by increasing times and `m` litke this :
[[1., 1.],
[2., 2.],
[3., 3.]]
I hope it's more clear like this... Thank you

Comment: `m.sort()` will sort `m` the way you are asking. I still don't understand what you are trying to do with `i`

Comment: I want to sort acconding to increasing datetime no according to the values of my measurements...

Comment: There is no way to performe this ??? For example if I have a = numpy.array([[4,3,2],[2,8,6],[1,4,7]]) and I want to have array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 8, 6],
       [4, 3, 2]]) where only the first value is evaluated to sort and the others columns elements of the row are place in the correspondant order ...

Comment: You've already accepted an answer. That tells me that the problem has been solved. If this is not the case, please post detailed I/O specs in the question